# Get data from text file and Check List in List

Tags: python

sorry maybe it is a very easy question but i can't find it.
i have a text file and it has a data

```
[3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

in it.

I want to read this file, add all this data in one array.
after this i want to check it with

```
with open("data.txt", "r") as fd:
    lines = fd.read().splitlines()


print(lines)

games = [3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3]
print(type(lines))

if lines in games:
    print("OK")
else:
    print("NO")
```

I can see lines is a list, games is a list, but i can't find it in lines list.

May you help me pls

Comment: what you trying to check with `line in games`

Comment: Do you want to compare each element, one by one, in line and games? If so, use `for line, game in zip(lines, games)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want  you can't check if the list exists in one array
I suppose you want to check if games exist in the file or not

```
 with open('data.txt') as f:
       l=[ line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]
    
    print(l)
    games = '[3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3]'
    print(type(l))
    if games in l:
        print("OK")
    else:
        print("NO")
```

Comment: Thank you, is games data is a string ?
This code works like this, but i want to check another list, should is convert is to string for check ?

Comment: I add 
`
games2 = str(games)
`
and use games2, this works

Answer (score 0):

This should works with one line:

```
games = [3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3]    
print(["NO", "OK"][sum([str(games) ==  line for line in open(r'data.txt').readlines()])>0])
```

Comment: Thank you, print is working but it was just test, i want to use IF after this code. How can i edit it like it.

Comment: if sum([str(games) ==  line for line in open(r'data.txt').readlines()])>0

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to check `lines` is equals `games` and not `games` in `lines`, this should work:

```
games = [3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3]

with open("data.txt") as fd:
    for lines in fd.read().splitlines():
        print(f'{lines} OK') if lines == str(games) else print(f'{lines} NO')

# [3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3] OK
# [1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3] NO
```